# Terraform AWS Multi Account Access Scenario

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws, infrastructure-as-code

I have set up a new AWS account and enabled organizations and Identity Center. Within this, I have created a test account as a sandbox for now. Also, we currently have one existing separate AWS account with all our infra there.

I have set up one IAM user for terraform in the new management account, and added it to a group which has a policy that allows it to assume a role in any other account having a name like 'terraform*'. In my test account, I've created a role called 'terraform', and allowed any user from the management account with a name like 'terraform*' to assume this role.

I am able to then user the IAM user from the management account, to perform actions on the test account via the cli using the assume role. What I am not clear on is in terraform I need the following

1. Backend should use a profile that writes to S3 in my existing AWS account since all our state and infra is there already.
2. Use credentials from my new management account's IAM user to get a token to access the new sandbox account.
3. Use the temporary credentials from 2 above to have terraform create infra in the sandbox account.

It seems at most you can configure a backend in a separate account, and then in your provider section define an 'assume_role' block, but not sure how to manage passing the IAM user credentials to be used to then assume that role. Or if this is possible to do in a CICD scenario as well ?

If there is another way to do this, please let me know, for both a manual and CICD use case.

**EDIT***
I also wanted to ask how you guys are managing to access different accounts, if you use the 'assume_role' in the aws_provider of your TF script, then this would have to be different for every account you want to run the script in. Is there a simple way to manage this ?